# Minimizing css files

Tags: css, minify

I want to know how CSS files can be minimized. Currently, I am using external sites like [CSS Minifier](https://cssminifier.com/) to compress CSS files. However, after removing the whitespaces, comments, etc, the file sizes are only reduced by 10-15%. How do frameworks like Bootstrap manage to make the minimized versions to be only kilobytes.

As an example, say my CSS is:

```
body {
    background-color: #ff0;
}
```

The reduction goes from 28 bytes to 22 bytes but other css files that have a lot more characters are still significantly smaller than this.

Comment: You could use something like gulp (https://gulpjs.com/) or grunt (https://gruntjs.com/)

Bootstrap is using grunt actually

Comment: Turn on [gzip](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/EnableCompression) compression

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score -2):

Actually The Minifying Code Means It's Remove This thing From Your code

- White space characters
- New line characters
- Comments
- Block delimiters

It reduces the amount of code that has to be transferred over the web and Speed up Your Site to Load Fastly.but is unreadable format.